# Convert from Numeric to Time in seconds

Tags: r, time

I have a list of durations that it took to complete a survey. Currently in numeric form.

```
    duration
    275
    207
    197
    251
    651
    278
    20
    343
```

`class(survey$duration)`
gives "numeric"

I want R to read these as seconds. I don't need any dates or anything, same output as it was original but for R to recognize it as time, not numeric.

I have tried
`survey$duration<-as.POSIXct(strptime(survey$duration, tz = "GMT", format = "%S"))` but the result gives dates as well.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Just so we can help you out a little more, what is your reason for needing R to know that the column duration is seconds? What is your end goal?

Comment: agree with @JForsythe.. this sounds a bit like a XY-problem..

Comment: Sorry! I am new to R. I am cleaning my data and I just thought that the time it took people to do the survey should be read as time, rather than numeric. No specific reason! Just trying to neaten up the data. Maybe I don't need to do it then!

Comment: No problem just trying to help you the best we can. This is going to come down to personal preference. For me I would leave the column in the numeric class and just make sure I treat that column as seconds in the rest of the code or analyses.  It keeps your code simple and doesn't rely on external packages.

You could convert it to the duration class using the code I provided from the Lubridate package but unless you had a particular reason to do so it doesn't provide much more functionality (though it could help with conversions if that was your end goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lubridate library can store times as Durations, Intervals, or Periods. This might be what you are looking for:

```
duration_Vec<-sample(1:1000,10)

library(lubridate)
as.duration(duration_Vec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the numeric value in a `period`, see [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) :

```
lubridate::seconds_to_period(survey$duration)

lubridate::seconds_to_period(275)
[1] "4M 35S"

lubridate::seconds_to_period(275)+lubridate::seconds_to_period(300)
[1] "9M 35S"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could `data.table`'s `as.ITime()`

```
duration <- c(275,207,197,251,651,278,20,343)
library( data.table )
data.table::as.ITime( duration )

# [1] "00:04:35" "00:03:27" "00:03:17" "00:04:11" "00:10:51" "00:04:38" "00:00:20" "00:05:43"
```

you will encouter issues if you've got values > 24 * 60 * 60